# Error in Calender Library

Tags: codenameone

The Calender Library throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException in an iOS App, wenn the description or location of an event is empty. The error occurs in class EventInfo (Constructor) and could be fixed with the following if-statements.

Am I right or do I miss something?

```
    id = element.getFirstChildByTagName("id").getChildAt(0).getText();

    if (element.getFirstChildByTagName("title").isEmpty())
        title = "";
    else
        title = element.getFirstChildByTagName("title").getChildAt(0).getText();

    if (element.getFirstChildByTagName("description").isEmpty())
        description = "";
    else
        description = element.getFirstChildByTagName("description").getChildAt(0).getText();

    if (element.getFirstChildByTagName("location").isEmpty())
        location = "";
    else
        location = element.getFirstChildByTagName("location").getChildAt(0).getText();

    startTime = new Date(Long.parseLong(element.getFirstChildByTagName("startTimeStamp").getChildAt(0).getText()));
    endTime = new Date(Long.parseLong(element.getFirstChildByTagName("endTimeStamp").getChildAt(0).getText()));

    if (element.getFirstChildByTagName("allDayEvent").isEmpty())
        allDayEvent = false;
    else
        allDayEvent = "true".equals(element.getFirstChildByTagName("allDayEvent").getChildAt(0).getText());
```

Comment: If that works, you might consider forking the Github project, adding the fix, and submitting a pull request. It would get fixed pretty quick that way probably.

Comment: Yes that looks correct and +1 on what james said. If not you can file an issue.

Comment: Because I don't have any experience with Github I prefer to file an issue with a link to this entry.